# Is $\{\} ∉ A$ true or false, if $A = \{1, 2, 4, a, b, c\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$A = \{1, 2, 4, a, b, c\}$. 
$\{\} ∉ A$ **(true)**. 
My solution for this question is true. Since $\{\}$ is not an element of $A$. But at college I showed this question to my teacher and he said it is **false** because $\{\}$ is a subset of $A$ not an element. What's the correct solution for this?
PS: Here is the question from the book circled in red. 
[image]

Comment: What are $a,b,c?$

Comment: @gammatester elements in set A.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy elements in set $A$ indeed, and one of them could equalize $\{\}$, right?

Comment: @drhab I updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I preassume that the symbols $1,2,4$ do not denote the empty set.

Then: $$\{\}\notin A\text{ is true if }a\neq\{\}\text{ and }b\neq\{\}\text{ and }c\neq\{\}$$

Otherwise it is false.

If nothing is known about $a,b,c$ then you should state that the statement is *not true in general*.

Further $\{\}$ is indeed a subset of $A$ but that is not relevant here.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Why didn't you assume that a, b, c are English alphabet characters?

Comment: Because in set-theory **everything** is a set, so $a,b,c$ must be notations for sets. Your update has no effect on my answer: it is not true in general.

Comment: The book author answered it **true** in the answers appendix.

Comment: Well, then I disagree with the author. Let your teacher read this and ask him/her what he/she thinks of this.

Comment: So if {} ∉ A is false. Then {} ∈ A is true?

Comment: No, $\{\}\notin A$ is not true *in general*. That means that it is not true under all possible conditions. That depends on $a,b,c$. Also the statement is not false *in general*. You simply have not enough information and cannot say things as "it is true" or "it is false".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84464/discussion-between-mohamed-magdy-and-drhab).

Answer (score 0):

The empty set is a subset of every set.

For the set $A$ In the question , the empty set is not an element of the set.

Comment: But who guarantees that e.g. $a\neq\varnothing$?

Comment: You are correct but in general we do not denote the empty set by $a$

Answer (score 0):

> …he said it is **false** because $ \{ \} $ is a subset of $ A $ not an element.

If it's, as he said, not an element and "$ \notin $" means "is not an element of", then it's obviously true.

Comment: The fact that $\{\}$ is a subset of $A$ does not exclude that $\{\}$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: That's true, but **if** the instructor is correct, then it's true.

Comment: The real question is: "is $\{\}$ not an element of $A$?" It is not: "is the instructor correct?"

Comment: Yes, but there was confusion on the part of the student due to what the instructor said, so it was a question and clarifying that should help somewhat.